# Load page with tables minimized by default

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with multiple tables containing data.

I have a simple script for expanding/collapsing my tables..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('th').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('thead').next('tbody').find('tr').toggle();
    });
});
```

..which is working fine.

### Fiddle

---

My question, how can I have the tables **minimized** by default when the page renders up?

**Note:** I want to save resources (optimization) since these tables really contains loads of data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS is better.

*css*

```
table tbody tr {
    display: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9KQGc/)

However You can programmatically trigger click event.

*jQuery*

```
$('th').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('thead').next('tbody').find('tr').toggle();
}).click(); //Just called click handler here
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3FV6Y/)

Comment: Wow, that easy huh. Thanks. Will accept as answer when I am eligible.